# fire TV stick adb install apk won't work

Tags: android, adb, amazon-fire-tv

I have been banging my head against the wall for the past couple of hours trying to install kodi on a fireTV stick.

I first tried with adblink, connected to the device, then installed the apk and the loading bar is just entering in a never ending loop without installing anything.

So I went ahead and installed adb to sideload the app mannualy with cmd.

```
c:\adb>adb connect 192.168.0.48:5555
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 192.168.0.48:5555

c:\adb>adb install C:\Users\sguerin\Downloads\kodi-16.1-Jarvis-armeabi-v7a.apk
```

it connects just fine but when I try the install command it just stay like this for ever and never display anything else...

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have enough storage left on the device, and if you are giving it permission to install from unknown sources,  if so, to see if the issue is with sending the app to the device, or actually installing it onto device try to push the apk first to the device, then install it (you can choose to use the package name of the app)

`adb push /computer/folder/app.apk /device/folder`

`adb shell pm install -r "/app/in/the/device" 
pkg: /data/local/tmp/packageName`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you found the answer you were looking since this post ,as it has been 3 years now but these commands work. It was only the 1st part of your command line that was wrong

pm install -r --user 0 /

You can also change the   "  -r   " to a number of different options, depending on what you want for the APK to do

ADB command cheat sheet
https://www.automatetheplanet.com/adb-cheat-sheet/

This command is if the APK is on device already in download folder on firestick, if in different folder change the path accordingly

pm install -r --user 0 /storage/emulated/0/Download/nameofapp.apk

Example
pm install -r --user 0 /storage/emulated/0/Download/TDUK-4k-Helper_1.3.apk

I've found this method to be fastest. I keep a folder of the best, and most up to date streaming apks that work on fire TV devices on my Android phone and use an application called Send files to TV (Which is on Google play store on my phone, and on the Amazon app store on any fire TV device. Then I send all the apks from my phone to the fire TV device using WiFi connection, which usually takes less than a minute with this apk. Then use remote ADB shell app on my phone to install all the apps on fire TV device using ADB command, which installs them without installation permission prompt. The same commands will work with a PC ADB command

Send files to TV
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details%3Fid%3Dcom.yablio.sendfilestotv%26hl%3Den&ved=2ahUKEwiHq6O5kP7pAhWyKH0KHar-AwcQjjgwAXoECAEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1GU9VjAetrW_0uC3zJQy99&cshid=1592028553525

Remote ADB Shell
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details%3Fid%3Dcom.yablio.sendfilestotv%26hl%3Den&ved=2ahUKEwiHq6O5kP7pAhWyKH0KHar-AwcQjjgwAXoECAEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1GU9VjAetrW_0uC3zJQy99&cshid=1592028553525

Make sure to rename APK file so there are no spaces ( you can substitute with the following " _     -      .   " or any of these characters or symbols that are commonly found in APK file names.   " ( )    {  }    [ ]  " Also if you have multiple files/commands to run you can add them to your script by putting a semicolon "   ;   "  between each command and run them all at once on 1 ADB command script

Hope this helps